# Building Apache and PHP without mariadb in YOCTO

Tags: build, yocto

I'm building a Yocto Project with PHP and Apache. (under Yocto 2.1)
I've added `apache2 php` and other packages to my `IMAGE_INSTALL`.

Why is `mariadb` included? How can I prevent that mariadb is built?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the PHP recipe, you will see its default package configuration is mysql sqlite3 imap and/or pam;

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "mysql sqlite3 imap \
                   ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'pam', 'pam', '', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG_class-native = ""

PACKAGECONFIG[mysql] = "--with-mysql=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${prefix} \
                        --with-mysqli=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/mysql_config \
                        --with-pdo-mysql=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/mysql_config \
                        ,--without-mysql --without-mysqli --without-pdo-mysql \
                        ,mysql5"

PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--with-sqlite3=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          --with-pdo-sqlite=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                          , \
                          ,sqlite3"
PACKAGECONFIG[pgsql] = "--with-pgsql=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix},--without-pgsql,postgresql"
PACKAGECONFIG[soap] = "--enable-libxml --enable-soap, --disable-soap, libxml2"
PACKAGECONFIG[apache2] = "--with-apxs2=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/apxs,,apache2-native apache2"
PACKAGECONFIG[pam] = ",,libpam"
PACKAGECONFIG[imap] = "--with-imap=${STAGING_DIR_HOST} \
                       --with-imap-ssl=${STAGING_DIR_HOST} \
                       ,--without-imap --without-imap-ssl \
                       ,uw-imap"
```

However, since there is no mysql recipe in the open-embedded-OE yet.  So they use mariadb to replace it.

```
require mariadb.inc

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DSTACK_DIRECTION=-1"

DEPENDS += "mariadb-native ncurses zlib readline libaio libevent"

PROVIDES += "mysql5"

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "mysql5"
RREPLACES_${PN} += "mysql5"
RCONFLICTS_${PN} += "mysql5"

RPROVIDES_${PN}-dbg += "mysql5-dbg"
RREPLACES_${PN}-dbg += "mysql5-dbg"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-dbg += "mysql5-dbg"

RPROVIDES_${PN}-leftovers += "mysql5-leftovers"
RREPLACES_${PN}-leftovers += "mysql5-leftovers"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-leftovers += "mysql5-leftovers"

RPROVIDES_${PN}-client += "mysql5-client"
RREPLACES_${PN}-client += "mysql5-client"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-client += "mysql5-client"

RPROVIDES_${PN}-server += "mysql5-server"
RREPLACES_${PN}-server += "mysql5-server"
RCONFLICTS_${PN}-server += "mysql5-server"
```

You can either remove mariadb by changing the `PACKAGECONFIG` instead of using mysql use pgsql. Add this line to your `conf/local.conf`

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-php ?= " sqlite3 imap pgsql apache2 "
```

Comment: I don't need a Database Package. No PG, mariadb, mysql.

Comment: The answer is in the line PACKAGECONFIG ?= " sqlite3 imap pgsql apache2  " . try to Figure it out yourself.